# MSBuild: How to ensure AfterBuild target always runs in a C++ project

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have added the following `AfterBuild` task to a `.vcxproj` file:

`<Target Name="AfterBuild">
   <Message Text="Hi" Importance="high" />
</Target>`

It seems to run only if the the C++ code is built (or if I do a rebuild):

`1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  SomeClass.cpp
1>  ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj -> 
1>  Hi
D:\Projects\CppTest\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.lib
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========`

It doesn't run  when the the C++ code is up-to-date:

`========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========`

How can I make it *always* run? I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 7):

I got around this issue by adding the following lines to my `.vcxproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DisableFastUpToDateCheck>true</DisableFastUpToDateCheck>
</PropertyGroup>
```

It seems to force the IDE to actually run MSBuild.

I tested it in Visual Studio 2015. Adding the same lines to an imported `.targets` file did not help.

Answer (score 5):

The line

```
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

means that Visual Studio didn't run MSBuild at all.

For incremental builds VS uses File Tracker to intercept file operations being performed by compiler and linker. Results can be fould in *ProjName*.tlog folder. In subsequent builds VS checks dates of files listed in .read and .write files and decides whether to run MSBuild. This feature is described in Hashimi S., Bartholomew S. - Using MSBuild, 2nd Edition - 2013, "File Tracker" chapter.

Some of possible solutions:

1. Use FileTracker API in your custom build tool.
2. Manually write file name(s) produced by your tool in some .write file (this solution is simple but is not guaranteed to work in future VS versions).
3. Build your solution by MSBuild instead VS.
4. Build your solution from bat-file, which calls devenv first then your tool.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting "Run the post-build event:" in project properties in Visual Studio, and you need to set it to: "Always" for the post-build event to run always.

I guess it's now set to "On successful build".

Comment: Sorry. Bit of a mixup. Although I mentioned csproj in the question, and I'm indeed experimenting in a csproj, I actually need this for C++ project (vcxproj file). So while csproj PostbuildEvent offers the "Always" setting, vcxproj doesn't. Which means "Always" setting wont work for me. Sorry. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Also note that "Always" run the post-build event does not affect how the AfterBuild target is handled.

Answer (score 0):

Build your project with detailed logging (/v:detailed or /v:diag) and find the target which being run last but present in both cases (lets say it's a made up target "FinalCleanup"), then hook your post-build target like this rather than by the special name

```
<Target Name="RunMyLastTarget" AfterTargets="FinalCleanup">
   <Message Text="Hi" Importance="high" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally went with [`Custom Build Step`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126324.aspx). To ensure that it always runs I set the `Outputs` field to some dummy file path. Since the dummy file path is never present, the `Custom Build Step` always runs. It is hacky, but it gets the job done.